# Open SSO Fedlet for .Net Change Home Folder

Tags: single-sign-on

I have an ASP.Net application which uses Fedlet from Oracle.  It's all working but I want to move the configuration from the App_Data folder to App_Data\Fedlet since we have all our configurations and extensions sitting in the App_Data (in neatly organised subfolders).

I've checked the Fedlet.dll.config file, but can't find any way to maybe reconfigure the folder but if there's any place to change it, I'm going to guess that's the place to change it.

Any pointers would be much appreciate as I've been searching for hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't found any answers anywhere on the net regarding this and since I managed to guess my way through, I decided to post the answer here for future reference both for myself and others.

If you place your web pages into a subfolder (example /pages/) then just place an app_data folder into the new folder (example /pages/app_data/) an